# how to show multiple markers on Google maps with java script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add multiple markers on Google maps with below script but no changes,
coordinates i need to use are posted on input field which i access with :`var latidudedb = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
var longitudedb = document.getElementById("longitude").value;`

please help me ,you're  assistance is highly appleciated

Javascript code **edited**:

```
var lat = -1.970579 //default latitude
  var lng = 30.104429; //default longitude
   var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); //set default 
    coordinates
     var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ //set marker
        position: homeLatlng, //set marker position equal to the default coordinates
      map: map, //set map to be used by the marker
     draggable: true //make the marker draggable
      });

         var myOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-1.935114, 30.082111), //set map center
zoom: 17, //set zoom level to 17
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //set map type to road map
         };

       var map = new 
   google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions); 
    //initialize the map
       //if the position of the marker changes set latitude and longitude to
        //current position of the marker
 google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, 'position_changed', function(){
      var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().lat(); //set lat current latitude where the marker is plotted
    var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().lng(); //set lat current longitude where the marker is plotted
});
   $('#plot_marker').blur(function () {
    $.post('/dashboard/names/DateString', $('mapform').serialize(), function 
 (data) {
        },
      );
 homeMarker.setMap(map); //set the map to be used by marker
  homeMarker.setPosition(map.getCenter()); //set position of marker equal to 
        the current center of the map
     map.setZoom(17);

 //get latitude and longitude from interface
 var latidudedb = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
var longitudedb = document.getElementById("longitude").value;
 //set the coordinates of the selected place
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latidudedb, longitudedb);
 //set marker position
homeMarker.setMap(map);
homeMarker.setPosition(position);
//set the center of the map
 map.setCenter(homeMarker.getPosition());
 map.setZoom(17);
```

Comment: I don't see that you are instantiating any markers besides the one assigned to homeMarker.  You would need to create a new google.maps.Marker for each marker that you want to appear on the map.